# How can I use multiple iframe apps without asking for login again?

Tags: typescript, iframe

I have a microfrontend that delivery some content. I want to display this content in an iframe, and I am using single SPA and SystemJS to import different microfrontends into one container app. This container app contains a login page to be able to navigate to routes.

The problem is: When I pass an existing route to the the `src` of the iframe, it requires to login again to be able to access to this content. This iframe is displayed in a modal.

How can I "share" the login in all the iframes?

Answer (score 1):

If everything is on a single domain, you should be able to use a cookie to share a token with the iFrame